# Solve Project Euler challenge #1 using only LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, functional-programming

Project Euler's [problem #1](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1) basically involves finding the sum total all numbers that are less than 1000 and divisible by either three or five. This would be very simple using LINQ if there was some sort of pre-existing list containing all integers between 1 and 999 (inclusive).

Does LINQ have a built-in way to generate a sequence of integers?

Comment: But can you solve that problem _without_ using `Enumerable.Range`?

Comment: @Rubens Farias: Are you asking if I could use LINQ without using Range?  If so, then no. I originally solved it using imperative style. In the process, it occurred to me that it might be one-liner if LINQ could be used.

Comment: I suggested you to try solve that problem without loops or sequences.

Comment: @Rubens Farias: Using recursion?

Comment: without recursion too =)

Comment: @Rubens Farias: I just created a fairly simple math formula to solve it. Is that the approach you're hinting at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<int> seq = Enumerable.Range(1, 999).Select(x => x);
```

Create a sequence of squares:

```
IEnumerable<int> squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x);
```

Sequence of odd numbers:

```
IEnumerable<int> oddNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(x => x % 2 != 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can chain up the LINQ `Enumerable.Range` (wich takes the start index and the amount of numbers you need), `Where` with your both conditions and `Sum` together.

The `% == 0` (modulo operator) ensures that your number is divisible by the other number.

This gives the following LINQ one-liner :

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Where(number => number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0).Sum();
```

Comment: I was deliberately not giving the full answer so the poster could experience the thrill of solving for themselves...